# Disable bootstrap tab

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-tabs

We have tabs at one of our page. What we are trying to do is disable the tabs when page loads initially and then enable them on click of a button. I have tried to add 'disabled' class when defining the tabs in my view:

```
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                                <li id="tbReady" role="presentation" class="disabled"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#ready" ng-click="tabClick('tbReady')">Ready to Submit</a></li>
                                <li id="tbAction" role="presentation" class="disabled"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#action" ng-click="tabClick('tbAction')">Action Required</a></li>
                            </ul>
```

When the page loads, they appear disabled but when you click a tab they become active again. I also tried to remove data-toggle from definition and then in tabClick function tried to return false but it is still not working

```
   $scope.tabClick = function (selTabName) {

            if ($('#'+selTabName).hasClass('disabled')) {
                    return false;
                }


            if (selTabName == 'tbReady') {
                listReadyRows($rootScope.caseFileId);
            } else {
                listActionRows($rootScope.caseFileId);
            }
          }
```

Can somebody see what I am doing wrong and point me to the right direction please!

Answer (score 0):

Why you are using twitter bootstrap for angularjs? https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ is a module which is used to make bootstrap things like (tabs, etc,.) in angularjs.

Why I am suggesting this is when you use twitter bootstrap in angularjs that won't work all the time.

If you use angular bootstrap [Angular-ui-bootstrap -- unable to disable tabs inside ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31374769/angular-ui-bootstrap-unable-to-disable-tabs-inside-ng-repeat) would helps you to disable tab.

Comment: You could be right but it's not possible to change it at this time because of the size of the project. So it would be nice if we could find a solution without changing the bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

on page load

```
$scope.Cssclass="enable";
```

on button click

```
$scope.tabClick = function (selTabName) {

        if ($('#'+selTabName).hasClass('disabled')) {
                return false;
            }


        if (selTabName == 'tbReady') {
           $scope.Cssclass="Disabled";
        } else {
            $scope.Cssclass="enable";
        }
      }
```

in you html

```
 <li id="tbReady" role="presentation" class="{{Cssclass}}"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#ready" ng-click="tabClick()">Ready to Submit</a></li>
```

I think it will work.